# =IMPORTXML in google sheets to auto update NFL scores

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets, xml-parsing, formulas

I'm using the following importhtml in google sheets and I tried a few options to get it to auto update, as much as possible, but all things have failed thus far.  I know a few people have had success with Apps Script, but I'm a little confused on how to get that to work for my example.  These are the following Importxml's I'm using:

A1= `importxml("http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml","//g/@q" )`
B1= `importxml("http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml","//g/@h" )`

Comment: You can use a time-based trigger in Apps Script and have it clear and reset the formulas for those cells and thereby force it to reload the NFL stats.

Comment: If you want to use Google Apps Script you could look [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).

Comment: Hi,Would anyone be able to assist me in a Apps Script. I'm seeming to fail at this.  I'd appreciate it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IMPORTXML into a Google Apps Script with Automatic Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45890812/importxml-into-a-google-apps-script-with-automatic-update)

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is create a new script. Then create 2 new script triggers. make it run on open and make another trigger time driven that runs every minute. 
Here is the script I use for the same purpose.

```
function GetNFLScore(){

var url = ('http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scores/scores.json');
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var content = res.getContentText();
var json = JSON.parse(content);   
var bye = "";

// Extracts the keys (these change every week)
var keys = [];
for(var k in json) keys.push(k);

// Declare array for results
var NFLResults =[];

// Make a Title Row
NFLResults.push(["Qtr","Time","Home","Pts","Away","Pts","Pos.","Down","To Go","Yard Line","Note","Network"]);

// Extracts the Games one per line
for(n=0; n<keys.length; n++)  {   
  var Clock = json[keys[n]]["clock"];                 // Kickoff time if pregame, Game Clock if game time
  var Qtr = json[keys[n]]["qtr"];                     // Gamestate (Pre, or Final), Game quater if game time
  var Home = json[keys[n]]["home"]["abbr"];           // Home Team
  var HsT = json[keys[n]]["home"]["score"]["T"];      // Home Total Score
  var Away = json[keys[n]]["away"]["abbr"];           // Away Team
  var AsT = json[keys[n]]["away"]["score"]["T"];      // Away Total Score
  var TV = json[keys[n]]["media"]["tv"];              // TV Network (NBC, FOX, ESPN, ect..)
  var YardLine = json[keys[n]]["yl"];                 // Current scrimage yard line
  var PosTeam = json[keys[n]]["posteam"];             // Team with ball possession
  var RedZone = json[keys[n]]["redzone"];             // Redzone boolean
  var Down = json[keys[n]]["down"];                   // Current Down
  var ToGo = json[keys[n]]["togo"];                   // Current To Go yardage for 1st down
  var Note = json[keys[n]]["note"];                   // Scoring play (Touchdown, Field Goal, Extra Point, Safety)

  // Correcting team abbr
  if( Home == "JAC" ){ Home = "JAX";}                 // JAC > JAX
  else if( Home == "WAS" ){ Home = "WSH";}            // WAS > WSH
  else if( Home == "LA"  ){ Home = "LAR";}            // LA > LAR

  if( Away == "LA"  ){ Away = "LAR";}      
  else if( Away == "WAS" ){ Away = "WSH";}
  else if( Away == "JAC" ){ Away = "JAC";}

  // Clear non-score related game data if game is final
  if( Qtr == "Final" ){ 
    Clock = "";
    PosTeam = "";
    RedZone = "";
    Down = "";
    ToGo = "";
    Note = "";
    TV = "";
  } 
  else if( Qtr == "Final OT" ){ 
    Clock = "";
    PosTeam = "";
    RedZone = "";
    Down = "";
    ToGo = "";
    Note = "";
    TV = "";
  }

  // Display Game data
  NFLResults.push([Qtr,Clock,Home,HsT,Away,AsT,PosTeam,Down,ToGo,YardLine,Note,TV]);
}

// Clear the bottom of the scoreboard from lack of scores caused by bye weeks
var rows = NFLResults.length
for(n=0; n<(17-rows); n++) {
  NFLResults.push([bye,bye,bye,bye,bye,bye,bye,bye,bye,bye,bye,bye]);   // N'SYNC
}

// Create new tab 'NFL Scores' if it doesn't exist.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var itt = ss.getSheetByName('NFL Scores');
if (!itt) {

    ss.insertSheet('NFL Scores');
}

// Push Scoreboard to spreadsheet
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('NFL Scores').getRange(1,1,17,12).setValues(NFLResults);}
```